XeLaTeX does not show latin extended characters with stix2
When running the code
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
    Zażółć gęślą jaźń.
\end{document}

through pdflatex I obtain the expected result:

However, using xelatex (or lualatex for that matter) I get:

and the log shows:
Missing character: There is no ż ("17C) in font t1-stix2text!
Missing character: There is no ł ("142) in font t1-stix2text!
Missing character: There is no ć ("107) in font t1-stix2text!
Missing character: There is no ę ("119) in font t1-stix2text!
Missing character: There is no ś ("15B) in font t1-stix2text!
Missing character: There is no ą ("105) in font t1-stix2text!
Missing character: There is no ź ("17A) in font t1-stix2text!
Missing character: There is no ń ("144) in font t1-stix2text!

This is all on TL2024, what am I missing?

The font doesn't have those characters, you could use newunicodechar and declare those slot sto use a classic tex \accent construct

The font does have these characters as is clearly documented: https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/blob/master/docs/STIXTwoText-Regular.pdf

The stix2 package is just for pdflatex.
For XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you want to use unicode-math or, but I wouldn't recommend it, only set the main text fonts with fontspec.
unicode-math
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

Zażółć gęślą jaźń.

$a+b=\sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k$

\end{document}


fontspec and legacy math
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{stix2}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

\begin{document}

Zażółć gęślą jaźń.

$a+b=\sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k$

\end{document}



Thank you, this does work. I didn't occur to me to look at unicode-math since I was thinking of this as a purely text font issue.

@KarolSzumiło The key is t1-stix2text: it shows that TeX is choosing a Type1 encoded font, but this won't work with a Unicode engine.

While I recommend the same solution as @egreg, another workaround that enables the legacy 8-bit fonts in LuaLaTeX is
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make missing characters an error.

\usepackage[UTF8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
    Zażółć gęślą jaźń.
\end{document}

